# Linux: GUI browsers do not honor '/etc/services' service names

Tags: linux, networking, browser, port

I'd like to avoid remembering common port names: e.g. for my CUPS it's `http://localhost:631/`.

I know that there're service names (named aliases for ports) in '/etc/services':

```
$ cat /etc/services | grep ipp
ipp             631/tcp     # Internet Printing Protocol
ipp             631/udp
```

And this works just fine:

> $ lynx `http://localhost:ipp/`

However, accessng `http://localhost:ipp/` does not work in Firefox, Opera, Konqueror.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the port number...

Comment: You seem to know nothing about laziness ;) Anyway, if there's such a feature - it should work! :)

Comment: The GUI tends to be segregated from the CLI apps (and configurations).  For example, you might setup a SOCKS tunnel in the GUI, but no command line apps know about it.

Comment: No, that's not the case. Browsers should just use getportbyname() for [a-z]* ports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be glad that the browser authors are sticking to the RFC ([1738](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738)). Chaos ensues when software makers don't follow RFCs, as those documents set the pace for standards on the Internet.

Using the port number instead of a service name is cross platform, as not all systems have consistent contents for /etc/services, or an equivalent.

Specifically in this case, section 3.1 of the RFC states:

> 3.1. Common Internet Scheme Syntax
>
> While the syntax for the rest of
>   the URL may vary depending on the
>   particular scheme selected, URL
>   schemes that involve the direct use
>   of an IP-based protocol to a specified
>   host on the Internet use a    common
>   syntax for the scheme-specific data:
>
> ```
>     //<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
> ```

...

> ```
> port
>     The port number to connect to. Most schemes designate
>     protocols that have a default port number. Another port number
>     may optionally be supplied, in decimal, separated from the
>     host by a colon. If the port is omitted, the colon is as well.
> ```

Comment: You're absolutely right. The only thing that confused me that lynx was able to handle the URL correctly. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

[File](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) [a](https://bugs.kde.org/) [bug](http://www.opera.com/support/bugs/). Wait, [someone](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=220473) [did](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125159) and it was rejected because it contradicts [RFC 1738](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738). So I guess you'll have to convince Mozilla (or Opera or KDE) to change their mind.

Comment: Or write an updated RFC and convince the 'net to accept it and THEN convince the browser teams to update their software. :-)

Comment: Or, if you use Firefox (or, well, anything other than Opera) write your own extension.